# getting rate ratios with CI for age adjusted rates in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get rate ratios from R using age-adjusted rates  that I got using the ageadjust.direct function (from epitools package). Does anyone know any function to achieve this?

Comment: What is the `ageadjust.direct` function, where can we find it? When using non-base functions, please post the name  of the package they come from.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.